# nth-child não funciona

Tags: html, css

```
    <div class="intro-frases" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1 data-segundos="4" class="frases pull-right" >TESTE 1</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1 data-segundos="5" class="frases">TESTE 2</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h1 data-segundos="0" class="frases">TESTE 3</h1>
        <h1 data-segundos="11" class="frases">TESTE4</h1>
        <h1 data-segundos="14" class="frases" style="font-size: 200px;">TESTE5</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1 data-segundos="5.5" class="frases">TESTE 6</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1 data-segundos="6" class="frases">TESTE 7</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.intro-frases h1:nth-child(1),
.intro-frases h1:nth-child(4) ,
.intro-frases h1:nth-child(7)

{
  color: red;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

era para colorir em vermelho e deixar em negrito o `teste1, teste4 e teste7`, há algo de errado no código?

https://jsfiddle.net/5j2erz59/

Comment: Funciona para mim... https://jsfiddle.net/5j2erz59/1/ Que browser estás a usar?

Comment: chrome, aqui está colorindo o: TESTE 1, TESTE 2, TESTE5, TESTE 6, TESTE 7 e não somente o teste1, teste4 e teste7 (era pra colorir e negritar somente estes)

Comment: Está errado isso. Experimente colorir o 1, 4 e 7 com cores diferentes que vc vai entender. veja separado para entender: https://jsfiddle.net/5j2erz59/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos entender o que acontece aqui

```
.intro-frases h1:nth-child(4)
{
  color: red;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

O seletor `:nth-child` significa "selecione o elemento que":

- Seja um elemento `h1`
- Seja o quarto *child* de um *parent*.

Você está imaginando que o *parent* é o `.intro-frases`, mas os seletores CSS não levam em consideração nenhum seletor anterior. O *parent* usado no `nth-child` é o primeiro *parent*, ou seja, é o elemento imediatamente superior na árvore DOM. É por isso que você está tendo um resultado inconsistente: como seus `h1`s não pertencem ao mesmo elemento pai, a ordem deles variam, e alguns assumem uma posição relativa a seu `parent` igual ao de outros.

O melhor nesse caso é adicionar uma classe aos elementos que você quer destacar.

Answer (score 4):

Como as respostas já explicam o problema, veja uma possível solução, acrescentando uma classe auxiliar com a numeração sequencial:

```css
.intro-frases .t1,
.intro-frases .t4,
.intro-frases .t7 {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
    <div class="intro-frases" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1 data-segundos="4" class="frases pull-right t1" >TESTE 1</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1 data-segundos="5" class="frases t2">TESTE 2</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <h1 data-segundos="0" class="frases t3">TESTE 3</h1>
        <h1 data-segundos="11" class="frases t4">TESTE4</h1>
        <h1 data-segundos="14" class="frases t5" style="font-size: 200px;">TESTE5</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1 data-segundos="5.5" class="frases t6">TESTE 6</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1 data-segundos="6" class="frases t7">TESTE 7</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

É claro que se forem fixas as condições, basta simplificar mais ainda, e apenas acrescentar uma classe extra somente nos ítens 1, 4 e 7:

```css
.intro-frases .red600 {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-frases" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1 data-segundos="4" class="frases pull-right red600" >TESTE 1</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1 data-segundos="5" class="frases">TESTE 2</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <h1 data-segundos="0" class="frases">TESTE 3</h1>
        <h1 data-segundos="11" class="frases red600">TESTE4</h1>
        <h1 data-segundos="14" class="frases" style="font-size: 200px;">TESTE5</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1 data-segundos="5.5" class="frases">TESTE 6</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1 data-segundos="6" class="frases red600">TESTE 7</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

O seletor `:nth-child(x)` seleciona elementos com a posição `x` relativos aos seus siblings, e não relativo ao resultado de um seletor. Ou seja se tivermos o HTML

```
div
    h1
div
    h1
div
    h1
```

e usarmos o seletor `div h1:nth-child(2)` nenhum desses `div` vai ser selecionado pois todos estão isolados. Da mesma maneira que `div h1:nth-child(1)` irá selecionar todos.

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/dyfsku1j/